# Не работает имитация нажатия на клавишу в игре Python

Tags: python, клавиатура

Делаю скрипт для самп, который будет открывать чат и писать туда что-то.
Код рабочий, но в самой игре F6 (открытие чата) не работает

```
import pyautogui
import time
while True:
    pyautogui.press('F6')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: а как вы расчитываете это будет работать?

Comment: цикл я просто для теста сделал. В целом мне нужно, чтобы в игре нажималась клавиша F6 (открытие чата), которая не работает в игре. На рабочем столе или в оконных программах всё работает

Comment: попробуйте вот эту штуку https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/